# How can I check what's wrong with USB stick?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, usb, external-disk

I plugged a USB stick into my MacBook 5 minutes ago, put 4 files on it.

After putting the files on it, I ejected the stick inside of Finder, waited for that to complete successfully, then took it out of my laptop.

Now (5 minutes later) I am putting the USB drive back into exactly the same port on exactly the same laptop. Finder does not show it, nor does Disk Utility. That's very frustrating.

I know the drive is not broken, because after this all happened (I didn't plug it in anywhere else in-between) I checked if it still works by plugging it into another MacBook.

I also know that the port on my macbook is not broken, because it can see another USB drive I own that I plug into it.

What can I do to begin debugging this? Is there a way to force macOS to "look" for USB drives connected?

Comment: Using Terminal, what do you get with the command `diskutil list` and `ls /Volumes`?  Do you see the name of the USB drive in either of these?